# Generate windrose polar plot from frequency table

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, windrose

I'm trying to port some code from MATLAB to Python, this snippet should generate two identical windrose plot starting either from [raw data](https://univpm-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/p012892_staff_univpm_it/ERfc3pRM8B5FtZb_BGdDL58BB6CQlaAYqWNtC534G3-yLg?e=XdGF2M) of direction and speed for waves of from already calculated [frequencies](https://univpm-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/p012892_staff_univpm_it/EVksX5KlRuRNoOS0DYgoTsUBDouKEOsQLvNn4bFXT_Z11g?e=UXD6Mx) for directions. The first case (with timeseries=1) works as expected, the second one does not. For the first case I used windrose module, but it is my understanding that it [cannot generate plots from frequencies](https://github.com/python-windrose/windrose/issues/71), so I'm trying manually using matplotlib but something is wrong. Any hints?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from windrose import WindroseAxes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

timeseries = 0
var1_label = 'Hs (m)'  # Choose between Hs (m), Tp (s), ...

# Input
if timeseries == 1:
    filename = '097.00W022.00N.DAT'
    day_start = datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 13)
    day_end = datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 22)

    var1_col = 5
    settoriH = np.arange(1, 4, 0.5)

    theta_col = 7

    nsettori = 12

    A = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, comment='*', encoding='cp1252')

    years = A.iloc[:, 0]
    months = A.iloc[:, 1]
    days = A.iloc[:, 2]
    hours = A.iloc[:, 3]
    minutes = A.iloc[:, 4]
    seconds = np.zeros_like(minutes)

    t = pd.to_datetime(dict(year=years, month=months, day=days, hour=hours, minute=minutes, second=seconds))

    Var1 = A.iloc[:, var1_col]
    theta = A.iloc[:, theta_col]

    theta[theta > 1000] = np.nan

    # Crop time series within selected time
    selected_indexes = (t >= day_start) & (t < day_end)
    Var1 = Var1[selected_indexes]
    theta = theta[selected_indexes]
    months = months[selected_indexes]
    t = t[selected_indexes]

    ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
    bins = np.arange(0, settoriH[-1] + 1, 0.5)
    ax.bar(theta, Var1, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white', bins=np.arange(0, settoriH[-1] + 1, 0.5), nsector=nsettori)
    ax.set_legend()
    plt.show()

elif timeseries == 0:
    filename = 'test_sca.csv'

    A = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, skiprows=2)
    settoriH0 = A.iloc[0, 1:-1]
    theta_sectors = A.iloc[1:-1, 0]
    theta_sectors = theta_sectors.astype(float)
    nsettori = len(theta_sectors)

    probability = A.iloc[1:-1, 1:-1]
    count2 = np.cumsum(probability, axis=1)
    settoriH = np.arange(1, 4, 0.5)

    count3 = interp1d(settoriH0, count2.T, kind='linear', axis=0)(settoriH)

    count3 = count3.T

    count3 = np.append(count3, count2.iloc[:, -1].to_frame(), axis=1)

    directions = np.arange(0, 360, 30)
    speeds = np.arange(1, 8, 1)

    count3 = pd.DataFrame(count3, index=directions, columns=speeds)

    ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
    cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap("jet", len(count3.columns))  # Color map for different speeds

    for i, speed in enumerate(count3.columns):
        radii = count3[speed]
        theta = np.deg2rad(count3.index -90 )
        width = 2 * np.pi / len(count3.index)
        bottom = np.zeros_like(radii) if i == 0 else count3[count3.columns[i - 1]].values
        bars = ax.bar(theta, radii, bottom=bottom, width=width, color=cmap(i))
    plt.show()
```

[This](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47248-wind-rose) is the code I'm trying to port in Python, specifically for the frequency part I comment this part from WindRose function:

```
% %% Bin intensities
% if isempty(vwinds)                                                         % If user did not specify the wind speeds he/she wants to show
%     if ~isempty(WindSpeedRound)                                            % If user did specify the rounding value
%         if isempty(NSpeeds); NSpeeds = 6; end                              % Default value for NSpeeds if not user-specified
%         vmax      = ceil(max(speed)/WindSpeedRound)*WindSpeedRound;        % Max wind speed rounded to the nearest whole multiple of WindSpeedRound (Use round or ceil as desired)
%                     if vmax==0; vmax=WindSpeedRound; end;                  % If max wind speed is 0, make max wind to be WindSpeedRound, so wind speed bins are correctly shown.
%         vwinds    = linspace(0,vmax,NSpeeds);                              % Wind speeds go from 0 to vmax, creating the desired number of wind speed intervals
%     else                                                                   % If user did nor specify the rounding value
%         figure2 = figure('visible','off'); plot(speed);                    % Plot wind speed
%         vwinds = get(gca,'ytick'); delete(figure2);                        % Yaxis will automatically make divisions for us.
%         if ~isempty(NSpeeds)                                               % If a number of speeds are specified
%             vwinds = linspace(min(vwinds),max(vwinds),NSpeeds);            % create a vector with that number of elements, distributed along the plotted windspeeds. 
%         end 
%     end
% end
% 
% %% Histogram in each direction + Draw
% count     = PivotTableCount(N,n,vwinds,speed,dir,NumberElements);
```

and call the function like this:

```
filename='test_sca.csv';

A=readmatrix(filename); settoriH0=A(1,2:end-1); theta_sectors=A(2:end-1,1); nsettori=length(theta_sectors);

probability=A(2:end-1,2:end-1); count2=cumsum(probability,2);

settoriH=1:0.5:3.5;

count3=interp1(settoriH0,count2',settoriH)';

count3(:,end+1)=count2(:,end);


[fig,count,speeds,directions,Table]=WindRose(count3,'FreqLabelAngle',30,'nDirections',nsettori,'vWinds',[0 settoriH],'TitleString',{'Polar plot';' '},'LabLegend',var1_label,'LegendVariable','H_s','AngleNorth',0,'AngleEast',90);
```